# merge 2 csv files via batch

Tags: csv, batch-file

I would like to combine 2 different csv files into one csv file.

The structure of csv (1):

```
Column A; Column B; Column C; Column D; Column E; Column F;
```

The structure of csv (2):

```
Column A; Column B; Column G;
```

Meaning, that first 2 columns in both files are equal.

I want to attach `column G` from `csv (2)` to the end of `csv (1)`.

Since I have a couple of files which I need to merge, I would like to do it using a batch file maybe?

I found a script that should do the trick in PowerShell but i am getting an error.

```
$csv1 = Import-CSV -Path y:\test\csv01.csv -delimiter ";"
$csv2 = Import-CSV -Path y:\test\csv99.csv -delimiter ";"
$csv1 | select *,@{n="Column G";e={$this = $_; $csv2 | ?{$_."Column A" -eq $this."Column A" and $_."Column B" -eq $this."Column B"} | select -Expand "Column G"}} | export-csv -Path y:\test\datei_neu.csv -delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I am getting an error that either the command is spelled wrong or could not be found.

Comment: Even if Google search was not successful, can you show what you have tried? My rough idea was be to convert both files into tables, merge and output the merged table as a CSV. However, I am not sure if Batch is capable of such thing. Can you consider other scripting option such (e.g. Ruby)?

Comment: This would be extremely inefficient using a batch file especially if the files are large.  The processing time would get exponentially slower as the size of the files grew.

Comment: That is ambiguous. Do you really mean `attach to the end of csv (1)` or `attach to the end of each matching line of csv (1)`

Comment: This is not a question but a (poorly specified) code request, which is clearly off-topic here. Please read the [tour] and these help articles: [ask] and [mcve]! As a starting point, take a look at [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Miller (here the binaries for Linux and Win https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/tag/5.4.0).

Starting from these 2 files

```
A,B,C
1,3,5
7,6,8

A,D
1,8
7,8
```

and run

```
mlr --csv cat then unsparsify --fill-with "" 1.txt 2.txt
```

you have

```
A,B,C,D
1,3,5,
7,6,8,
1,,,8
7,,,8
```

Comment: Well, you seem to have misunderstood the requirements of this question (which is actually off-topic here, because it is nothing but a code request)...

Comment: @aschipfl sorry